# why is only one field being displayed?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to print out the names of all the current users of the application, they print in the console however when the app runs only one of the names is displayed.

```
            func getData() {
                
              let db = Firestore.firestore()
                   
                   // Get data
              db.collection("users").getDocuments()
              {
                  (snapshot, err) in

                  if let err = err
                  {
                      print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    snapshot!.documents.forEach({ (document) in
                        let firstname = document.data()["firstname"]
                        print(firstname!)
                        self.studentlbl.text = (firstname! as! String)
                      }
                    )
```

How can this be fixed?
Thanks!

Comment: You aren't showing any of your UI code, but it looks like you only have one label. You'd either need multiple labels, a text view, or perhaps a table view that you can populate with that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only have one label view, so each time this line runs you overwrite the previous value of that label:

```
self.studentlbl.text = (firstname! as! String)
```

If you want to show all values in that single label, you can do:

```
self.studentlbl.text = self.studentlbl.text + (firstname! as! String)
```

Comment: Isn't the text field is optional, so that will fail on the first iteration?  Would need to unwrap somehow.  Easiest probably `self.studentlbl.text = (self.studentlbl.text  ?? "") + (firstname! as! String)`

Comment: this seems to be working, however the names are all displayed together. any idea on how to space out the names? thanks